# AS3 - swfaddress deep linking when someone pastes a url

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, deep-linking, swfaddress

I have swfaddress (2.4) working fine on my site - the back button works, I can copy and paste urls and be taken to the correct page, etc.

BUT, if I copy a url, say "http://mysite.com/#/bio", and paste it into a new browser window, the site always just loads to the home page after the preloader. What am I missing? Do I somehow need to check the url when the page loads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing any of your code...There's two events you're going to be interested in watching for. When your app starts up you should listen for

```
SWFAddress.addEventListener(SWFAddressEvent.INIT, __init);
```

Which would then register the `CHANGE` listener:

```
private function __init(event:SWFAddressEvent):void
{
    SWFAddress.addEventListener(SWFAddressEvent.CHANGE, __handle);
}
```

Your handler function should handle changes in the URL. This will handle the beginning url when it first initializes and when you use `SWFAddress.setValue()` to change the page:

```
private function __handle(event:SWFAddressEvent):void
{
    var address:String = SWFAddress.getValue();
    // -- perform actions based on addresss
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems that just registering for SWFAddressEvent.CHANGE fires the handler, without the need for init.